# How do I jump to a type declaration (implementation) in one project from another project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects in Eclipse, 1 and 2, with classes A and B respectively.

Both projects, 1 and 2, are open in Eclipse.

When I open A in 1 in Eclipse, there is a line like the following
`B b = new B();`

When I move my cursor on B and press F3 (Open Declaration), I get shown a compiled version of B, B', and the option to attach the source code. But if I do that and jump to the file, instead of navigating to project 2 in the Navigator or Project Explorer, Eclipse jumps to the included libraries and expands that class there. Is there any way to make it jump to the actual class B in project 2, and not some sort of copy, B*?

Comment: CTRL + mouse click on the class does not work? That's how I always do it and I don't need to do anything special to get it to work. But then again I use maven so my Eclipse project structure setup is mostly done automagically.

Comment: Yeah, I used to use maven, too. But now I'm on a team that uses ant... :'(

Answer (score 1):

This works for me -- I have a main project A and a supporting project B in eclipse; when I use F3 on a class declaration in A for a class in B, then it opens the source code in B in a Java editor.

Do you have B declared as a required project on the Project Build Path in project A's properties?  That's what I would suspect would do it.

Comment: No, I only looked at the Project References. What's the difference; what's the References used for (if not resolving that sort of thing)?

Comment: Well, I don't know the complete definitions, but it seems to me that references list things that you use, and required projects refers to things that you both use and work on source for, i.e., the required projects are things for which you would expect to have source there in the workspace.